# Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects extension's remote certificate invalid

Tags: vsix, vdproj, visual-studio-installer

When building the project in github actions, I use the Visual Studio Installer Projects extension.

This is my powershell script:

```
$installerUrl = 'https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/fd136a01-a0c8-475f-94dd-240136f86746/file/247375/5/InstallerProjects.vsix'
$vsixPath = "$($env:USERPROFILE)\InstallerProjects.vsix"
Invoke-WebRequest $installerUrl -OutFile $vsixPath
```

When i try to install my visual studio extension in my script i got this error:

```
Line |
   3 |  Invoke-WebRequest $installerUrl -OutFile $vsixPath
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: NotTimeValid

Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

How can i renew this certificate?